# DataContractSerializer - serialize string as value and not reference

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

I use `DataContract` serializer to serialize my data. I use `PreserveObjectReferences = true` because I need it.
I have two objects for example:

```
[Datacontract]
class A
{
  [DataMember] string _name;
  ...
  public A(string name)
  {
    _name = name;
  }
}
```

and

```
[Datacontract]
class B
{
  [DataMember] string _name;
  ...
  public B(string name)
  {
    _name = name;
  }
}
```

Both have `_name` field.
Then I create instance of A and B where I use as a name of the second object the same name from object A:

```
var obj1 = new A("John");
var obj2 = new B(obj1.Name);
```

Then I serialize it, and XML contains:

```
...
<d11p1:_name z:Id="505">John</d11p1:_name>
..
<d11p1:_name z:Ref="505" i:nil="true" />
```

So the field `_name` of the second object is serialized as reference and not Value.

Then I don't need object A so I delete it. But I want to be abble to open an old saved file which contains data from class A, but in the new version of my program I don't need class A anymore.

The problem is that `DataContractSerializer` cannot deserialize instance of B because its `_name` is a reference to `_name` of A which is not deserialized (class is deleted).

Is there any way to force `DataContractSerializer` to serialize a string as Value type instead of reference?

I know that one solution is not to delete class A but it contains a lot of data which isn't important in the new version of my program.

Comment: Is B the new class you have created? Can you make changes to class B?

Comment: No the class B was in old version of the program too. It was serialized to XML file as I wroted. And it is needed in the new version of program. The new version of program have to read also saved files from old program. What do you mean by changes to class B?

Comment: I meant if it is possible to make changes to code in class B. Since you have instructed serializer to preserve references, it will.

Comment: why are you desirailzing it in this manner 

why not  

var s = A.Name;
var b = new B(s);

Comment: Yes it is possible to make changes in class B. By second sentence I don't understand what do you mean :)

Comment: I think it doesn't matter if you use new B(s) or new B(A.Name). String is reference in C# so the result is the same.

Comment: @Philipe Do keep in mind that strings in .NET are immutable - even if you preserve the reference between the two, `object.Equals(old, new);` will still yield false; they'll point to two different instances of the same string.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is the way the `PreserveObjectReferences` works.

You could try `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` instead of `PreserveObjectReferences`. It works with Reference Type only.

Serialized object which contains list

```xml
<M1 z:Id="i2">
    <name>name1</name>
</M1>
<M2 z:Id="i3">
    <name>name1</name>
</M2>
<M3 z:Ref="i3"/>
<list>
    <m2 z:Ref="i3"/>
    <m2 z:Id="i4">
        <name i:nil="true"/>
    </m2>
</list>
```

Comment: So you mean do not use PreserveObjectReferences for all objects but only for my own classes. So the string will be excluded. But what with other system references like array? I have my data tree (which I serialize whole) composed from about 50 classes and some of classes can share the same array. So if I use PreserveObjectReferences  only for my classes then for examle arrays will be created as two different instances.

Comment: If your array contains reference types, it will be displayed as Reference only. (post edited)

Comment: I mean for example two objects with same array:<br/>
class M1  
{  
  Person[] _list;  
  public M1(Person[] list)  
  {
    _list = list;
  }
}  
and the same class M2 and I will create them with the same array(reference)